# NodeJS Copying File over a stream is very slow

Tags: node.js, performance, file-io, stream, pipe

I am copying file with Node on an SSD under VMWare, but the performance is very low. The benchmark I have run to measure actual speed is as follows:

```
$ hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   12004 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6025.64 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1370 MB in  3.00 seconds = 456.29 MB/sec
```

However, the following Node code that copies file is very slow, evne teh consequent runs do not make it faster:

```
var fs  = require("fs");
fs.createReadStream("bigfile").pipe(fs.createWriteStream("tempbigfile"));
```

And the runs as:

```
$ seq 1 10000000 > bigfile
$ ll bigfile -h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mustafa mustafa 848M Jun  3 03:30 bigfile
$ time node test.js 

real    0m4.973s
user    0m2.621s
sys     0m7.236s
$ time node test.js 

real    0m5.370s
user    0m2.496s
sys     0m7.190s
```

What is the issue here and how can I speed it up? I believe I can write it faster in C by just adjusting the buffer size. The thing that confuses me is that when I wrote simple almost pv equivalent program, that pipes stdin to stdout as the below, it is very fast.

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

And the runs as:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 | pv | dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in 174MB/s] [        <=>                                                                                ]
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.78077 s, 186 MB/s
   1GB 0:00:05 [ 177MB/s] [          <=>                                                                              ]
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.78131 s, 186 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 |  dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.57005 s, 193 MB/s
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.5704 s, 193 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 | node test.js | dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.61734 s, 233 MB/s
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.62766 s, 232 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 | node test.js | dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.22107 s, 254 MB/s
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.23231 s, 254 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 | dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.70124 s, 188 MB/s
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.70144 s, 188 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=128 | node test.js | dd of=/dev/null
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.51055 s, 238 MB/s
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.52087 s, 238 MB/s
```

Comment: don't copy files with node. just too much overhead

Comment: as you see, there is no overhead in piping stdout to stdin, and I suspect it is a buffer size issue with files.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but perhaps this helps in your investigation of the problem.

In the Node.js [documentation](http://www.nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering) about stream buffering, it says:

> Both [Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) and [Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) streams will store data in an internal
> buffer that can be retrieved using `writable.writableBuffer` or
> `readable.readableBuffer`, respectively.
>
> The amount of data potentially buffered depends on the `highWaterMark`
> option passed into the stream's constructor. For normal streams, the
> `highWaterMark` option specifies a total number of bytes. For streams
> operating in object mode, the `highWaterMark` specifies a total number
> of objects....
>
> A key goal of the `stream` API, particularly the [stream.pipe()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) method,
> is to limit the buffering of data to acceptable levels such that
> sources and destinations of differing speeds will not overwhelm the
> available memory.

So, you can play with the buffer sizes to improve speed:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var from = path.normalize(process.argv[2]);
var to = path.normalize(process.argv[3]);

var readOpts = {highWaterMark: Math.pow(2,16)};  // 65536
var writeOpts = {highWaterMark: Math.pow(2,16)}; // 65536  

var source = fs.createReadStream(from, readOpts);
var destiny = fs.createWriteStream(to, writeOpts)

source.pipe(destiny);
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should think again, adjusting it to that size makes it almost 2x faster, which is closer to the native speep. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why `highWaterMark` is not an option listed for `fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])` here:  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options , and also if it is possible to adjust the `highWaterMark` of a readable stream that is being returned from an api request?

Comment: I'm not sure why `highWaterMark` isn't listed on `fs.createWriteStream`, but you can pass it as an option and it will work.