# Why is streaming a response so much slower than sending a regular response in Node.js / Express?

Tags: node.js, express, node-streams

I'm using a Node.js / Express server to query a Postgres database and send the results to the browser as a CSV file.  The result set can get quite large (e.g. 50+ MB), so I thought it prudent to stream the results straight from the DB all the way to the browser like so:

```
const QueryStream = require('pg-query-stream');
const { Transform } = require('json2csv');

const pool = require('./pool-instance');

// ...some request handling code...

const client = await pool.connect();
const stream = client.query(new QueryStream(q.text, q.values));

stream.on('end', () => {
  client.release();
});

const json2csv = new Transform({}, {objectMode: true});
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=export.csv');

// pipe the query results to the Express response object. 
stream.pipe(json2csv).pipe(res);
```

This worked well when tested locally, but when I tested it over the network on a small server it **took over 20 seconds to stream a 1.3 MB file**.  So, I tried doing things in a more traditional way:

```
// Just load the full query results in memory
const results = await pool.query(q);

// Create the full csv text string from the query results
const csv = await parseAsync(results.rows);

res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=export.csv');

res.send(csv);
```

**This took only 2 seconds** for the same file.

Why is this?  Why is the streaming approach so much slower?

Comment: How are results if you omit the `json2csv` transformation in the streaming code?

Comment: The stream returned from node-postgres' `QueryStream` is an Object stream, so I had to convert it to a string in order to skip the csv transform and pipe it to `res`.  When I did that and skipped the csv it's still slow - just under 20 seconds.

Comment: If it makes a difference (I don't think it should), I'm consuming the response on the client side using `res.blob` and creating an `objectURL` with it.

Comment: How did you measure the 2 seconds?  Did you measure the time for the client to actually receive the whole content.  If you just measured the time for `res.send()` to run, that's not representative of the actual time for the client to receive it because `res.send()` is asynchronous.  It returns BEFORE the content has all been sent.  Also, your two examples don't look at all like similar code.  The first seems to have an object mode transform stream and the second calls some unknown `parseAsync()` function.  Those don't look like comparable code paths.

Comment: @jfriend00 I measured by looking at the Network tab in Chrome's DevTools (the waterfall specifically).  `parseAsync` is just an async method (from that same json2csv lib) that converts json to a CSV string.  So the upshot is I'm creating the full string and sending it all to the browser in one shot in that second path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and it seems that the reason is not related to node-pg but Node Streams workflow.
The problem is described here : [NodeJS Copying File over a stream is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005496/nodejs-copying-file-over-a-stream-is-very-slow)

> In the Node.js documentation about stream buffering, it says:
>
> Both Writable and Readable streams will store data in an internal
> buffer that can be retrieved using writable.writableBuffer or
> readable.readableBuffer, respectively.
>
> The amount of data potentially buffered depends on the highWaterMark
> option passed into the stream's constructor. For normal streams, the
> highWaterMark option specifies a total number of bytes. For streams
> operating in object mode, the highWaterMark specifies a total number
> of objects....
>
> A key goal of the stream API, particularly the stream.pipe() method,
> is to limit the buffering of data to acceptable levels such that
> sources and destinations of differing speeds will not overwhelm the
> available memory.

According to the QueryStream constructor def here : https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg-query-stream/src/index.ts#L24

you can override the highWaterMark settings to a higher value (default to 100).
Here I choosed 1000 but in some case, you might want to increase or decrease this value. I suggest to be careful with it, as it could leads to OOM problems if you are running this in production.

```
new QueryStream(query, [], {highWaterMark: 1000});
```

Or in your case :

```
const stream = client.query(new QueryStream(q.text, q.values, {highWaterMark: 1000}));
```

Also, you should make sure that no others streams piped with it has a lower `highWaterMark` value that could lead to slow the process.

For me this improved the speed to be as quick as direct download from the db.

---

Also, I found that under low performance CPU, my stream was still too slow. In my case the issue was the Express' compression() compressing the response with gzip. I set up the compression on the reverse proxy side (traefik) and everything was working well.

Comment: Thanks @Raphiki.  I tried your approach and it got me very close.  However, there were still two issues.  (1) Because these are object streams the `highWaterMark` refers to the number of objects, so 4096 was too high of a number.  (2) The json2csv stream default `highWaterMark` is 16, which created a bit of a mismatch with the query stream.  Setting the `highWaterMark` for both streams to 500 did the trick.  If you edit your answer accordingly, I'll accept it.

Comment: Right there is no reason to set this as a power of 2 value as its objectMode (I could have set 4000). Therefore in my case, setting `highWatermark` from 100 to 8000 speed up the process. Above 8000, I have noticed no difference. I believe this is highly related to the script used and the system running it. I could set it to 1000 what do you think ?

Comment: @MarkMcKelvy Updated my post. Also, I added an extra part that definitely solved speed performance at the end